# How should I connect my new bathroom light fixture?

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

I am replacing the light fixture in the bathroom. The old one has a fan, light and heater and so does the new one. I am unsure if I should connect any wires back to the white wire with the copper. I have never seen it where a copper wire and white wire are connected together.

I am attaching pictures of the old connection and the wires coming out of the ventilation fan. All together there are 4 switches but one of them is for the light above my vanity, others are for the exhaust fan. The switch on the top left is for my vanity light.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the switch box for the fan switch please?

Comment: How many switches are controlling the fan, light and heater? It makes a difference. If 1 switch all 3 new fan light and heater are combined if 2 switches the fan and light are normally combined and the heater is on the second switch, pro tip is do not disconnect anything until you know where it goes to. Pictures like this help but we only have 1/2 of the information needed to provide the answer,

Comment: How is it wired presently?  I see tape numbers on the black wires, that's important.  Also, the "bare wires" spliced to "white wires" means something truly evil and dangerous was done, but there may be a workaround to keep your functionality.  It will really help to see what is going on inside the switch box.

Comment: have you actually noticed that the wires are labeled? ... look for labels at the other end of the wires

Comment: It appears that you've now created two accounts and that's why you couldn't comment on your original question. Please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged.